# When did Svelte Kit routing get so difficult or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: routes, svelte, sveltekit

So I started learning Svelte Kit by watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydR_M0fw9Xc&t=505 and was amazed immediately...

One of the best things I saw was the easy routing.  The author of the video added an `About.svelte` file to the routes folder and went to localhost:5173/about and VOILA the page appeared!

When I tried this, it did not work.  I had to make a folder called `about` in the routes folder, then include a file inside of that folder called `+page.svelte`

Needless to say I do not like this method AT ALL.  Is there a way to use the older method instead?  Or did I make a mistake?  Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before now, any file under the `routes` folder is considered a route. However, based on [this reasoning](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5748), things have changed. Unless you want to settle for older SvelteKit versions, you can not do that again. I believe that this new method is not bad after all. It has some advantages which the previous one didn't possess. With time, I think you will get used to it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain.  Do you know how I would start a new Svelte Kit project using an older version?  Perhaps the one right before 1.0?

Comment: I wouldn't advise you to use older versions. The new routing method is better. Instead of having `routes/about.svelte`, create `routes/about/+page.svelte` and put the content of `about.svelte` into `about/+page.svelte`. It is recommended to use the latest library version when starting out.

Comment: It's hard to say this is a good decision. Now in the editor, all the open files are `+page.svelte`.
When I want to access a file quickly, open Go to and type in `page.svelte` and I see a long list of `+page.svelte`. It's inconvenient and somewhat a trouble to see project tree also.
That's why I come back to Next.js after a few months with SvelteKit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's the new way of routing. Each folder (route) can have independent server config and JavaScript files and even inner layouts.
I haven't yet gone through the new docs yet, this is just what I've been seeing in practice but here's a YouTube creator [@Hunterbyte](https://www.youtube.com/@Huntabyte) making tutorials with SvelteKit 1.0. (The one in your question is somewhat old)
Alternatively you could try out the official [SvelteKit tutorial](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/page-data). Happy Coding!